# unix shell поиск и замена строк в файле

Tags: unix, shell, поиск, замена

Здравствуйте, подскажите как найти и заменить все содержащиеся строки в файле httpd.conf используя **/bin/sh** ?

В файле есть строки с указанием директорий пользователей:

```
<Directory /home/user1/data/www/site1.org>
        Options -ExecCGI -Includes
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/user1/data:."
        php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>
<Directory /home/user2/data/www/site2.com>
        Options -ExecCGI -Includes
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/user2/data:."
        php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>
<Directory /home/user2/data/www/site3.ru>
        Options -ExecCGI -Includes
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/user2/data:."
        php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>
```

заменить строку

```
    php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>
```

на

```
    php_admin_flag engine on
    php_admin_value mail.add_x_header  On
    php_admin_value mail.log  "/var/log/phpmail/user1.log"
</Directory>
```

где **user1** = Directory /home/**user1**/data/www/site1.org

**если в кратце, то стоит задача отредактировать конфиг и добавить в  блоках директорий, в которых не прописан путь до логов,  путь до файла логов php mail()**

на выходе должно получиться что то вроде этого:

```
<Directory /home/user1/data/www/site1.org>
        Options -ExecCGI -Includes
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/user1/data:."
        php_admin_flag engine on
        php_admin_value mail.add_x_header  On
        php_admin_value mail.log  "/var/log/phpmail/user1.log"
</Directory>
<Directory /home/user2/data/www/site2.com>
        Options -ExecCGI -Includes
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/user2/data:."
        php_admin_flag engine on
        php_admin_value mail.add_x_header  On
        php_admin_value mail.log  "/var/log/phpmail/user2.log"
</Directory>
<Directory /home/user2/data/www/site3.ru>
        Options -ExecCGI -Includes
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/user2/data:."
        php_admin_flag engine on
        php_admin_value mail.add_x_header  On
        php_admin_value mail.log  "/var/log/phpmail/user2.log"
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот скриптец:

```
#!/bin/sh

user=

oneLine () {
  echo "$1"
  x=${1#*php_admin_value open_basedir \"/home/}
  if [ ".$x." != ".$1." ]
  then
    user=${x%%/*}
  fi
  if [ ".${1#*php_admin_flag engine on}." = ".." ]
  then
    echo "        php_admin_value mail.add_x_header  On"
    echo "        php_admin_value mail.log  \"/var/log/phpmail/${user}.log\""
  fi
}

IFS=
while read line 
do 
  oneLine "$line"
done
oneLine "$line"
```

а так вызывать:
`sh /path/to/script.sh < httpd.conf > httpd.conf.new`